# stepping through code between php and node servers

Tags: php, debugging

I was wondering how I can step through code between a node server and php server and client side code. I mostly want to see what's going on between the node server and the client side code especially with the ajax calls. They seem to be messing with the order of my lists. Something that could show the values of each data structure and how they change with each step would be amazing but I have yet to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use firefox's **firebug** extension and open up the Net tab to see the communications between the server and client. You can also use **firephp** plugin so that you can actually display your php logging on firebug.